# Gmail: What does "mark as spam" do with a spoofed email?

Tags: email, gmail, google-apps, spf, dkim

Due to spoofing problem, I have recently set up DKIM, and SPF record on my domain. I am using Google APPS for our organization. My emails are now getting checked, and I get a hard-fail SPF message, when I try to spoof my email using: https://emkei.cz/

**I have noticed the following behaviour:**

1. Email send from my organisation using Google Apps to a gmail.com account.

   - Message gets to inbox
   - Received-SPF: pass
   - Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass dkim=pass
2. Email send from https://emkei.cz/ to gmail.com account, using a "from" email that does **not** exist in my organisation.

   - Message usualy goes to spam
   - Received-SPF: fail
   - Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=hardfail
3. Email send from https://emkei.cz/ to gmail.com account, using a "from" email that does exist in my organisation.

   - **Message goes to inbox**
   - Received-SPF: fail
   - Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=hardfail

Now, since in 3., the spoofed email message made it to inbox although the SPF has hard-failed (why google?), what happens when I mark this message as spam? I do not feel at ease marking spoofed emails, which made it to inbox, as spam. I Am afraid my **real** email will not make it next time.

This is also a problem for my organization, because the spoofed emails that we try to prevent are done by people, not bots.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if the spoofed email comes from an IP configured as whitelisted or as an [inbound mail gateway](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60730?hl=en).

Check those settings at https://admin.google.com/ ||insert your domain here|| /AdminHome?fral=1#ServiceSettings/service=email&subtab=filters